# Add Software Request to Close -> Off Topic -> Belongs on another site?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration-path-request

Can we have https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ added as a close -> Off-Topic because -> Question belongs on another site option? Right now it only has this meta site as an option, but a lot of the time we close the question as just off topic when we can migrate the question to a stack exchange where questions like that are answered.

Current example that lead to this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193670/source-engine-map-editor-that-runs-under-linux

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea; softwarerecs is still in beta, and actually has rather strict requirements for questions.  The one question that's been migrated [got rejected](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14082/are-there-any-pc-games-which-are-similar-to-alias).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bad idea, because questions asked here will very rarely be even close to matching what Software Recommendations requires from their questions.

It is a much better idea to point to that site in the comments and *highlight their question requirements* so the person can ask a good on-topic question over there.

Answer (score 3):

It is by design impossible to have beta-sites on the migration options.

Also I would guess that game-recommendations are not well-recieved on software-recs, since they can't really fulfil their [question requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/352), especially the point "Features"